# import mysql.connector could not be resolved pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, mysql-python

Here are my codes

```
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
print(mydb)
```

My path is /mnt/c/Users/icelu/Downloads/Codes/Github/My-hw-codes.
I open myTest.py.
Import mysql.connector works.
But if I open My-hw-codes as my working directory, it doesn't work.
I wonder what's wrong with my path? I don't want to only open a single file.

Comment: Please include your code as text and not images.  Please clarify what exactly is your error?

Comment: Have you switched the python interpreter? It has no difference between you opening a file in a project or a single file. Could you attach the screenshot with the python environment?

Comment: Just edit my post, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: My current python interpreter is python 3.9.7

Comment: And it's python 3.10 if I open a single file. Problem solved, you're my hero. Thank you so much.